# Height 100% on several levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

In order to explain what I'm looking for I've made a jsfiddle to illustrate it. That means I have a solution, but this is not a code review question. I have already reviewed my own code and found that I don't like it. So it's there only for illustrative purposes, to show what I want to replace with a better solution. This one contains too many nested div's for my taste, and some JS/jQuery; I'd prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

The basic points are:

**1)** the body/main wrapper should always have the height `100%` even if the viewport size is changed (resize the window of the fiddle to see what happens)

**2)** The two div's with the borders within the `div#content`, i.e. `#nav` and `#article`, should also have the height `100%` (with `padding`/`margin`/`border-spacing`)

**3)** The height of the gray area within `#nav` should always be `100%` (again with some `margin`/`padding` as per the fiddle), no matter how little text/other stuff it contains. If the content doesn't fit on the screen, a vertical scrollbar should appear, and the background color should extend down to the content within the scrollable area with the same margin/padding as before.

**4)** The height of the right area with the green image should be `100%` as well, and the size of the image should adjust to the height of the container (up to the full size of the image; after that there should be empty space below it, but the bottom borders of both `#nav` and `#article` should still be horizontally synced at the bottom of the screen).

Any ideas (preferably without loading additional frameworks like bootstrap or using CSS flex or other poorly supported techniques)?

Here's the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c04oj6uy/2/)**

And the code is:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper-block">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
           Banner and stuff
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="inner-nav">
                <div id="v">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ullamcorper bibendum tortor, a euismod diam laoreet sed. Nunc massa augue, aliquam convallis erat id, rhoncus placerat lacus. Nullam tincidunt vulputate lacus, sit amet ullamcorper tellus egestas vel. Duis tincidunt faucibus erat et eleifend. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In varius tincidunt augue ut ullamcorper. Quisque vestibulum sit amet orci in ullamcorper. Integer at erat et diam lacinia volutpat vitae sed purus. Ut rutrum erat nunc, a adipiscing purus bibendum ac.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="article">
                <div id="inner-art">
                    <img id="pic" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/30ijbc3.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
}
html,body,caption,div,dd,dl,dt,fieldset,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,ol,ul,p,table,tr,th,td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body.js {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper-block {
    max-width: 842px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0.375em 0.0625em #777777;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1em;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
    display: table-row;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav {
    width: 36%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper-block, #wrapper, #content {
    height: 100%;
}
.js #wrapper {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#nav {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#article {
    width: 62%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#inner-nav {
    border: 1em solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E6E6DC;
}
#v {
    background-color: #E6E6DC;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 0.75em;
}
#inner-art {
    padding: 0.75em;
    height: 100%;
}
#pic {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS/jQuery

```
var cont = $('#content').height(),
    wrap = $('#wrapper').height(),
    win = $(window).height(),
    head = $('#header').height(),
    twoems = (wrap - head - cont);

$('#nav, #article').height(win - twoems - head - 2);

$('#wrapper').css('visibility','visible');

$(window).resize(function() {
    var newWin = $(window).height();
        if($('#wrapper').height() > newWin) {
            $('#nav, #article').height(newWin - twoems - head);
        } else {
            $('#nav, #article').height($('#content').height()-2);
        }
});
```

Comment: According to your divs: you can use HTML5 new tags instead of divs, such as `<header>,<footer>,<aside>, <main>, <nav>` etc. (e.g. instead of  `<div id="article"> </div>` use `<article> </article>`. And about JS/jQuery: I don't think 15 lines of script code is too much :) I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes, I know about the HTML5 tags, but I chose to use divs since I needed some "unnecessary" divs anyway to make the layout work. As for the script code, I should have said just "JS/jQuery", not "too much JS/jQuery", since one line is too much. :) I'd prefer a pure CSS solution. I have edited my question in order to clarify that. But if I'm going to rely on JS only to make the design work, maybe I could skip the hassle with "display: table", although I'd probably need a little more JS?

Comment: @linurb In my knowledge it can be done by pure CSS only If the `#header` has an explicit `height`.

Comment: You mean this: http://jsbin.com/lopej/1/edit

Comment: Full view: http://jsbin.com/lopej/1 -- it's 100% high, sticky footer (and header if you want), and the interior columns are 100%. If the height is high enough, then there's no vertical scrollbars, otherwise, when the footer hits, it shows the scrollbars. It was a pain.

Comment: I don't think that's what I mean. Turn of the JS and the 100% of the interior columns are gone. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami How would you do that?

Comment: @linurb Is it allowed to use CSS3 features and also set a fixed `height` on the header?

Comment: @Hashem Yes, that's perfectly fine as long as the features are reasonably well supported (IE8- isn't necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352635/height-100-on-several-levels#comment39540923_25352635):

> Supporting IE8- isn't necessary

Thus, as a pure CSS solution you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) expression in order to calculate and specify `height` of the elements properly.

What you need to do is:

1. Specifying an explicit `height` on `#header`
2. Calculating the `height` of `#content` element by using CSS `calc()` function.

You'll end up with:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/c04oj6uy/3/)**

```css
#header {
    height: 2.5em;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 2.5em);
}
```

You might also want to consider using `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixes [to support](http://caniuse.com/calc) the old versions of Webkit based web browsers and Mozilla Firefox.

It's worth noting that `calc()` [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility).

---

<sup>PS: I've refined the HTML structure and also some CSS declarations to get rid of redundant stuff. No need to use CSS tables here.</sup>

Comment: Great, thanks! It seems to be working just as it should. I had completely missed the calc() feature. Very nice. :)